# Load multiple JSON files as bootstrap table entries

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap-table

I am new to javascript and I would ask help to load multiple JSON files in order to populate a bootstrap table.

I was able to generate a table by manually merging the files content in a single variable `list`:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('table').bootstrapTable({ 
    data: JSON.parse(list) 
  }); 
});
```

How can I extend this code to load multiple files?
Consider also that I need to read all the JSON files contained in a particular folder (unknown number and name of the files).

Comment: how do you expect to "load multiple files"?

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS the extent of reading files is when the file as passed as an input i.e.

To quote: [API/FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

> Important note: FileReader is used to read file content from the
> user's (remote) system in secure ways only. It cannot be used to
> simply read a file by pathname from a file system. To read files by
> pathname in JavaScript, standard Ajax solutions should be used to do
> server-side file reading, with CORS permission if reading
> cross-domain.

If it's an option, consider using Node.js where you have access to the 'fs' libary.

https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

For this, it is better use [data-ajax option](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#ajax):

```
<div id="toolbar">
  <button id="data1" class="btn btn-secondary">Data source 1</button>
  <button id="data2" class="btn btn-secondary">Data source 2</button>
  <button id="data3" class="btn btn-secondary">Data source 3</button>
</div>
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-toolbar="#toolbar"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-side-pagination="server"
  data-ajax="ajaxRequest">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<script>

  // urls to your data sources
  var data1 = 'json/data1.json'; 
  var data2 = 'json/data2.json'; 
  var data2 = 'json/data3.json'; 
  
  let selectedData = ''; 
  
  $(function() {
    // switch you data source here
    $('#data1').click(function() {
      selectedData = data1;
      $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
    })

    $('#data2').click(function() {
      selectedData = data2;
      $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
    })

    $('#data3').click(function() {
      selectedData = data3;
      $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
    })
  })
 
  // your custom ajax request here
  function ajaxRequest(params) {
    $.get(selectedData).then(function (res) {
        params.success(res)
    })
  }
</script>
```